How can I lay Laminate floor around a cavity
the floor I’m laying on has floor cavity sockets, how can I lay laminate around this?


Without a picture, I can only guess you will need to remove the trim and run the floor and reset the trim

Just uploaded a picture, the sockets are sunken in the floor

Working around those sockets is not all that different from working around a stairwell or a post. Do you have any more specific questions?

My concern is the plank shifting forward as there is nothing blocking it. A stairwell or post keeps the plank in place but for this socket dip it would just be blank space

Most laminate floors clip together, so one or two plank/s moving enough will take some work.  The planks usually have a fancy tongue and groove, with the tongues having a lip to them, to lock them together.

there should be a cover and the cover should have a lip that will prevent planks from falling in.

There is no cover unfortunately but the clip and lock system does make sense, thank you

Purchase a Transition moulding to match your flooring.
It can take a little math, but figure the correct space to leave room between the edge of the box cavity and the flooring for installation of the transition.
Lay the flooring.  Finish around the floor box with the moulding in a picture frame pattern for a nice finished look.

Amazing thanks I’ll try this
